# Python3 Parallel Processing 2 loop Functions

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I want to execute 2 looping functions at the same time. This is my code, even if I use Multiprocessing, the 2 functions don't get executed at the same time. (Note: Each function generate a HTTP Server, which mean they will never end as a function.). The first function I generate a PHP HTTP Server, and the second function I generate a Python3 HTTP Server.

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

def python_server():
    os.system('python -m SimpleHTTPServer 1337')

def php_server():
    os.system('php -S localhost:1338')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread_1 = Process(target=python_server())
    thread_1.start()

    thread_2 = Process(target=php_server())
    thread_2.start()
```

When script is executed, only the Python Server is opened, the PHP Server is still being queued. My goal is to open these 2 servers at the same time.

Comment: In your example the first function executes in the current process and only the result would be passed as argument to `target`. Don't _call_ the functions, just pass them to `target` like `Process(target=python_server)`.

Comment: Thanks, never thought of this but it worked :)